# git rebase local branch on origin/master

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I have problems with git:

let's say there was a commit c1 on origin/master
1. I made a branch "local-work", committed and pushed the branch to origin.

```
c1 <- origin/master
c1 <- c2 <- origin/local-work
c1 <- c2 <- local-work
```

So far so good.
The idea was to work further in this branch and push my work to origin. But I also want to always have the newest from origin/master. 
So, I committed again:

```
c1 <- c2 <- c3 <- local-work
```

Then, my colleagues pushed their work:

```
c1 <- c4 <- origin/master
```

This is where I wanted to get their work into my local-work branch before pushing the branch to the server. So I did rebase:

```
c1 <- c4 <- c2 <- c3 <- local-work.
```

Now I tried to push my work to origin/local-work and it was rejected. How can I fix the situation?

Thank in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was rejected because rebasing changed your commits.

If only you have worked on `local-work`, force the push (which overwrites the remote branch)

```
git push -f origin local-work
```

If others have worked on `local-work`, you should have merged instead of rebasing.